# Insert Textinputs in an array React Native

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native

the goal of this app is to insert the TextInputs and the state of color in an array called `listPeople` by clicking the Button represented below through the `submitItem` , the TextInputs are `name` and `lastName` which I get from the component and `color` I get from `this.props.route.params`. I put a `console.log` to see what's wrong and the problem is that when I launch the code in the terminal it gives me back just the color output like I represented below, which is not even in the form of an array.

**Terminal**

```
blue
```

**Screen**

```
export class List extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          listPeople: [],
          name: '',
          lastName: '',
          color: '',
            };
      }
    
    
      submitItem = ( list ) => {       
        const  listPerson = {
            color: this.props.route.params,
            name: name,
            lastName: lastName,
          };
          this.setState({ listPeople: [...this.state.listPeople, listPerson]})
          console.log(listPeople)
      };
    
    
      
    
      render() {
        const { color } = this.props.route.params;
        return (
          <Container>
            <Header>
                <Button transparent>
                  <Icon
                    name="checkmark"
                    onPress={() =>
                      this.submitItem(
                        color,
                        this.state.name,
                        this.state.lastName,
                      )
                    }
                  />
                </Button>
            </Header>
            <View style={{ alignItems: "center" }}>
                  <TextInput
                    placeholder="name"
                    textAlign="center"
                    onChangeText={(name) => this.setState({ name })}
                  />
                  <TextInput
                    placeholder="lastName"
                    textAlign="center"
                    onChangeText={(lastName) => this.setState({ lastName })}
                  />
             </View>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because you're passing 3 params on your `this.submitItem` try this :

```
submitItem = ( color, name, lastName) => {       
        const  listPerson = {
            color: this.props.route.params,
            name: name,
            lastName: lastName,
          };
          this.setState({ listPeople: [...this.state.listPeople, listPerson]})
          console.log(listPeople)
      };
```